DBT Duplicate row detected during DML action - Snowflake
Creating an incremental model using the MERGE strategy with a unique key. The unique key to merge on is a surrogate key of columns from the table.
When I run this incremental model I get the error: Duplicate row detected during DML action.
I have confirmed this key is unique for incrementation so I am very confused by this error.
-- Model Configuration
{{  
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = ['loan_history_key']
    )
}}

-- Import dependencies
-- depends_on: {{ ref('dim_loans') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('dim_cifs') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('fact_loan_details') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('fact_loan_payments') }}
-- depends_on: {{ ref('dim_dates') }}

-- Select data and generate surrogate key
WITH loan_histories AS (
    SELECT
        dim_loans.loan_key AS loan_key,
        dim_dates.date_key AS as_of_date_key,
        -- Add other necessary fields
    FROM
        {{ ref('dim_loans') }} AS dim_loans
    JOIN
        {{ ref('dim_dates') }} AS dim_dates
        ON dim_loans.some_date = dim_dates.date
    -- Include other necessary joins
)

SELECT
    {{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['loan_key', 'as_of_date_key']) }} AS loan_history_key,
    *
FROM
    loan_histories

-- Handle incremental updates
{% if is_incremental() %}
WHERE  
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(as_of_date_key), 'YYYYMMDD') >= current_date - interval '3 day'
{% endif %}


I have simplified the code significantly because this model is very large and would be annoying to read through

Put both a not_null and a unique test in place first, and check which row is the culprit. You will most probably have a join or some other logic creating duplications in loan_history_key 

Try to see if for that particular key if there are more than 2 row in source with the filtered result. Sometimes when there are multiple rows in source with same key DBT is unable to decide which row needs to be updated with the target row.

Try run dbt run --full-refresh, then go to Snowflake and check loan_history_key for uniqueness and that it is not null. Most probably you will find duplicates, so you can debug from there.

When handling duplicates in your data, consider the following points:

Business Logic and Uniqueness: Determine if unique records are necessary. If your business logic requires unique records, implement a mechanism to enforce this.

Surrogate Key: If duplicates are part of your business logic, create a surrogate key to uniquely identify each record. This allows you to manage and reference duplicates effectively.

Error Identification: If duplicates are due to errors from the source, flag these issues to the relevant teams for resolution.

Duplicate Handling Logic: Develop a logic to manage duplicates when they occur. One approach is to select the record with the latest created_on date, ensuring you retain the most recent information.


